# OkHttp Reverse Http

Tags: java, okhttp

How to implement reverse http as described in [link](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-lentczner-rhttp-00.txt) using OkHttp

Currently my implementation is something like
Issue is I have to parse http responses which I don't feel safe, its just a coarse implementation, if someone can provide a  better alternative

```
String request = "POST /reverse HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                        "Upgrade: PTTH/1.0\r\n" +
                        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" +
                        "\r\n";

Socket socket = null;
try {
    socket = client.socketFactory().createSocket(ip, port);

    final PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    // send the reverse http request
    out.write(request);
    out.flush();

    // read the reverse http response
    String reverseResponse = readResponse(in);

    if (!reverseResponse.trim().startsWith("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols")) {
        throw new IOException("can't setup reverse connection");
    }

    while (!stopped) {
        String eventData = readResponse(in);

            out.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
                        "Content- Length: 0\r\n\" + " +
                        "\r\n");
            out.flush();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (socket != null) {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you're having?

Comment: Issue update in question

Comment: Is there any reason you wouldn't use web sockets for bi-directional communication? There are several libraries with full implementations + fallbacks for older browsers like SignalR (dot net) and socket.io (node)

Comment: Server part is proprietary and only supports Http and expects reverse Http for some calls

Answer (score 0):

**Trivia:** Coincidentally, there is a different guy who [drafted](http://reversehttp.net/specs.html) a similar solution and coincidentally named it reverse-http as well. This spec has a [Reference Java Implementation](https://github.com/tonyg/reversehttp), but not useful to you, since you are in no control of the server side.

**On track**:

I could find a Javascript implementation for the reverse-http that you are interested in [here](https://github.com/watson/reverse-http). Take a look for implementation hints, but, I guess you already have details.

For your problem, you would need a code fragment that can handle http requests (an http server functionality), while being embedded in a http client library.

Using Okhttp (I hope you are referring [this](https://github.com/square/okhttp)) to achieve what you want may be a bit of work. It provides Websocket support, which is a more evolved version of reverse-http. So, you may try customizing the [Websocket implementation](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/ws/RealWebSocket.java) of okhttp for your case.

A simplistic solution like yours, where you need not parse the http response can be achieved by adapting the code of popular `NanoHTTPD` library. Latest releases have added more dependency but an [older release](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/blob/v1.28/NanoHTTPD.java) has just 1 java file, with no dependency and ideal for such adaptations.

Comment: @ingsaurabh, did this answer help?